# CheckBox values in Html.Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

I have a model with a List of invoices. I am displaying this list of invoices in a grid. I would like to have a column of check boxes in the grid so I can perform some additional logic. How would I go about reading the values of these check boxes when I post? Basically what I need is to have a `Html.CheckBoxFor` in a column for each of the items in the list. I don't think that's possible but is there a way to have something similar?

Here's my grid:

```
<% Html.Grid(Model.Invoices)     
       .Attributes(@id => "tblInvoiceSearchResults", @class => "tablesorter", style => "width:100%")
       .Empty("No invoice exist with that criteria")
       .Columns(
        col =>
            {
              col.For(c => c.InvoiceNumber).Named("Invoice Number");
              col.For(c => c.InvoicePurchaseOrderNumber).Named("PurchaseOrder");
              col.For(c => c.InvoiceStatus).Named("Invoice Status");
              col.For(c => c.OpenAmount.ToMoneyDisplay()).Visible((bool)ViewData["canSeePricing"])
                    .Named("Open Amt").Attributes(align=>"right");
              col.For(c => c.OriginalAmount.ToMoneyDisplay()).Visible((bool)ViewData["canSeePricing"])
                    .Named("Original Amt")
                    .Attributes(align => "right"); 
              col.For(c => c.InvoiceDate).Named("Invoice Date");
        }).Render();
 %>
```

Comment: What grid library are you using? Or is this hand rolled?

Answer (score 1):

After review, I'm taking a guess that you are using the mvccontrib-grid? If so take a look at this answer from DD: [Mvc Contrib grid with checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273236/mvc-contrib-grid-with-checkbox/4274616#4274616)