# How to render a checkbox in the header row using MvcContrib?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvccontrib-grid

I am trying to render a "Select All" checkbox in the header row of my grid using the following.

```
column.For(x => Html.CheckBox("InvoiceSelection", false, new {@class = "checkbox reqPayment ", value = x.InvoiceId}))
          .Header(o=>"<th><input type=\"checkbox\" id='chkHeader' />Select All</th>")
          .Encode(false)
          .HeaderAttributes(@class => "text-error");
```

However, this does not render as expected and instead renders with an `<a>` as the content

```
<tr><th class="text-error"><a href="/Invoices?Direction=Ascending"></a></th>
```

The 'row' checkboxes render correctly and have already tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273236/mvc-contrib-grid-with-checkbox) with no luck but not sure if this is applicable to Nuget package I am using at the moment - [MvcContrib.Mvc3-ci 3.0.100](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcContrib.Mvc3-ci/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your above code with the same version and it works fine for me.

Might be worth checking the following:

Do you have the specific reference in the view?

```
@using MvcContrib.UI.Grid
```

It could be getting mixed up with another `Html.Grid` helper if you have used a different one elsewhere in the project.

Could there be some other factor that is adding the sort functionality afterwards like a jQuery plugin?

**Edit (by question author)**

@hutchonoid raised a good point about "other factors" which resulted in me finding the solution.

There are some notes about the final solution

- If you are using a sortable grid, you need to set the `Sortable(false)` on the column
- There is no need for the `<th>` elemement
- The solution I ended up using

  ```
  column.For(x => Html.CheckBox("InvoiceSelection", false, new {@class = "checkbox reqPayment ", value = x.InvoiceId}))
        .Header(o=>"<input type=\"checkbox\" id='chkHeader' />")
        .Encode(false)
        .Sortable(false)
        .HeaderAttributes(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "style", "width:20px" } });
  ```
- Add for completeness, here is the JS that toggles the "Select All" functionality

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#chkHeader').change(function() {
          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              $('.reqPayment').attr('checked', 'checked');
          } else {
              $('.reqPayment').removeAttr('checked');
          }
      });
  });
  ```

Comment: I have no other plugins and do have the correct references.Does your result render the checkbox in the header row?

Comment: It does, I did it with jus a plain mvc install out of the box new project

Comment: after some digging it required a few additional tweaks. the `th` wrappers needed removing

Comment: Nice one. Pleased u fixed it. I will watch out for that in the future.